# Perl is not fully executing when called from Python script

Tags: python, mysql

I have a `Python` script, which calls a `Perl` script that parses some files and produces output files. Again these output files are uploaded into `MySQL` database using the Python script. The Perl script takes around `5-7 mins` to parse some files and produce the output files that the Python uses to upload.

The Python script is like:

```
import subprocess
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./parser.pl"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.close()

#Now, load the output files from parser.pl to database.

sql01 = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sequence.parsed' INTO TABLE nasequenceimp FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"""

try:
  c.execute(sql01)
  conn.commit()
except StandardError, e:
  print e
  conn.rollback()
```

But, it seems that Python script is terminated and the Perl script continues to parse the files. So, Python shoots error `sequence.parsed does not exist`

Why is the Python script not waiting for the Perl to complete executing?

Comment: @mpapec, what was the scope of adding my Perl code in this question. Did you read my question before voting it down?

Comment: just removed perl tag, didn't down voted your question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent process doesn't wait for the child process spawned by `subprocess.Popen` by default. You should call:

```
pipe.wait()
```

after `subprocess.Popen`. It will wait the child process to terminate and let your python script continue.

Or you can just use `os.system()` instead.

Comment: Should I have to put `pipe.stdin.close()` after `pipe.wait()`?

Comment: @aki2all `pipe.wait()` will block your python script so you should put it after `pipe.stdin.close()`.